# How to get the current url path using hook router in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, hookrouter

I'm new to react and react hooks. I'm using *hookrouter* package and I tried to googling about the question, but didn't find much about it.

**What I want?**

I'm trying to get the current url path. For e.g. for `https://example.com/users/temp`, I want to get `/users/temp`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found on [github doc](https://github.com/Paratron/hookrouter/blob/master/src-docs/pages/en/04_other-features.md#using-the-uri-path).

```
import {usePath} from 'hookrouter';

const PathLabel = () => {
    const path = usePath();
    return <span>Your current location: {path}</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to let you know there's also a generic way to return the path using Javascript, in case you're not using hookrouter on a different project

Just invoke `window.location.pathname`

I'm using it for setting active className for links in my Nav component based on which route the client is on using a ternary expression. Example:

```
const NavList = props => {
    return (
        <NavContainer>
            <ul>
                {routes.map(({ key, href, label }) => (
                    <A href={href} key={key} className='route-link'>
                        <li
                            className={href === window.location.pathname ? 'active' : null}
                        >
                            {label}
                        </li>
                    </A>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </NavContainer>
    );
};
```